# Can't use $(warning) in ifeq branch

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to output a message if debug is enabled

```
ifeq ($(debug), 1)
    $(warning Enabled debug mode, do not use it in production environment)
    ccflags-y += -DDEBUG
endif
```

It won't work because "make" complains about the "warning" line:

```
Makefile:11: *** recipe commences before first target.  Stop.
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't add tabs inside the `if` body.

Comment: That's a weird feature, why is it designed like that?

Comment: @daisy No idea. :(